# how to calculate contour integral for semi circle as shown

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

[image]

Hi all, how do I apply contour integral $I =\oint z^ndz$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ to solve the above diagram??

Thanks for helping everyone..

Answer (score 1):

Let $z:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb C,\ z (t)=1/2 e^{2\pi i t} -1/2$,  be the parameterization of the curve $\gamma $. Then $\int _ \gamma z^n dz=\displaystyle \int _0 ^1 z (t)^n z'(t)dt$. Nevertheless, z^n has an entire primitive, thus integral depends only on extremal points.

Comment: thanks for replying but how do u obtain the expression z(t)??

Comment: You plug in $z(t)$ for $z$ in the integrand, which depends on $z$. In this case the integrand is $z^n dz$, so $z(t)^n=(1/2e^{2\pi it}-1/2)^n$.

Comment: kk @B.Pasternak, but how do you obtain the expression for z(t)^n??

Comment: anyway thanks for helping..

Comment: The expression of z comes from the circle $\cos\theta + i \sin \theta ~ (\cos\theta,\sin\theta) $

Comment: You don't need an explicit expression for $z(t)^n$ to do the integral.

Comment: @john you may use the binomial formula to calculate this integral by hand, but what Blumer tells you is that you needn't bother. Since $z^n = \left(\frac{1}{n+1}z^{n+1}\right)'$, you have $\int_\gamma z^n dz = \left. \frac{1}{n+1}z^{n+1}\right|_{-i}^0 = \frac{-(-i)^{n+1}}{n+1}$.